# adding to a textarea, is there a faster way than appending? How to add a whole list at one time not line by line...JAVA

Tags: java, string, list, append, textarea

Im using java and this program is basically disecting a txt file and using N (Integer 1-4) to create a Super String to analyze txt files. I have them being sorted using radiobuttons alphabetically and by occurrence..my question is how do I add the whole list at one time instead of adding line by line, I feel like line by line is an inefficient way of appending to my textareas. Any suggestions? I have a for each statement to add line by line and keep count.

```
     String[] storage = new String[N];
    words = new CountLinkedList<SuperString>();
    words2 = new OrderedLinkedList<SuperString>();
   for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
     storage[i] = scan.next().toLowerCase().replace(",","").replace(".","");

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0;i<=N-2;i++)
        storage[i] = storage[i+1];
      storage[N-1] = scan.next().toLowerCase();
      storage[N-1] = storage[N-1].replace(",","").replace(".","");
      SuperString ss = new SuperString(storage);
      SuperString ss2= new SuperString(storage);
      words.add(ss );
      words2.add(ss2 );
    }

    textarea.setText("");
    textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
        }
    SuperString[] ss = new SuperString[words.size()];
    SuperString[] ss2 = new SuperString[words2.size()];
    int i=0;
    int count =0, count2= 0;


    for(SuperString word: words)
    {
      ss[i] = word;
      i++;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(SuperString word: words2)
    {
      ss2[j] = word;
      j++;
    }


    Arrays.sort(ss, new SuperStringCountOrder());

   if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
     textarea.setText("");
    for(SuperString word : ss)
    {
      count++;
        textarea.append(count+"   "+ "  "+word+"\n");     
    }
    }
    if(alphabetical.isSelected())
    {
      textarea.setText("");

     for(SuperString word : ss2)
    {
       count2++;
        textarea.append(count2+"   "+ "  "+word+"\n");     
    }
```

Comment: Append to a `StringBuilder` instead of to the field directly, convert the builder to a `String` using `toString()`, then append the `String` to the field

Comment: What is `SuperString` and why are your instances sharing storage arrays? Also, why is the caller constructing storage arrays for `SuperString` instances?

Comment: How do I append to a StringBuilder

Comment: `StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();str.append("whatever");System.out.println(str);`

Comment: `for(SuperString word : ss)
    {
      count++;
      string.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word+ "\n");
      string.toString();
    }
    if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
     textarea.setText("");
     textarea.append(string.toString());
    }`

Comment: This works fine BUT when I switch from occurrence to alphabbetical and back.. the textarea doesnt clear and I know it's my toString() method but I dont know where to call it for it to work

Comment: It just adds to the textarea instead of replacing the old StringBuilder>...??? please help

Answer (score 0):

This works fine! BUT when I append to textarea it keeps my old list and just adds to it even though I have textarea.setText("") each time occurrence and alphabetical are selected?

```
  for(SuperString word : ss)
    {
      count++;
      string.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word+ "\n");
      string.toString();
    }
    if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
     textarea.setText("");
     textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
     textarea.append(string.toString());
    }


     for(SuperString word : ss2)
    {
       count2++;
       string2.append(Integer.toString(count2)+ "       "+ word.toString()+ "\n");  
    }
         if(alphabetical.isSelected())
    {
      textarea.setText("");
      textarea.append(string2.toString());

    }
```